# Raster artefacts after saving to GeoTIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, srtm

When processing DEMs created using downloaded SRTM data (initially HGT files) I produce a nice-looking product; however, saving this as a GeoTIFF creates square artefacts which are plain to see (and negatively affect the generation of stream networks and catchments). The only real technical difference I can see between rasters is the GDAL driver:

[image: Left: good! Right: Bad!]

[image: Left: details of good version. Right: details of bad version.]

Note that the colour stretch for both images is exactly the same. So is the CRS. I'm scratching my about what the issue might be.

Comment: Which tool do you use to convert from HGT to GTiff? Can you check the band *type* (~bit depth per pixel; test it e.g. with `gdalinfo [filename]`) of both files? Which compression is the GTiff using?

Comment: Hmm.. I just use QGIS to export the HGT to GTiff

Comment: Could you share the output of `gdalinfo [filename]` of input and output file?

Comment: I'm not a gdal command-line user; would this be best done using QGIS from the python console?